# Strimzi kafka - kafka connect not getting installed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I've Strimzi Kafka setup on GKE, and it is working fine.
I've a requirement to setup MirrorMaker2 to push data from source kafka topic to target Kafka topic.
From what i understand, MirrorMaker2 requires KafkaConnect.

I'm trying to install KafkaConnect on the GKE cluster in namespace kafka-connect, the yaml used is the following.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
  name: my-connect-cluster
#  annotations:
#    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
spec:
  version: 3.0.0
  replicas: 1
  bootstrapServers: versa-kafka-gke-kafka-bootstrap:9093
  tls:
    trustedCertificates:
      - secretName: versa-kafka-gke-cluster-ca-cert
        certificate: ca.crt
  config:
    group.id: connect-cluster
    offset.storage.topic: connect-cluster-offsets
    config.storage.topic: connect-cluster-configs
    status.storage.topic: connect-cluster-status
    # -1 means it will use the default replication factor configured in the broker
    config.storage.replication.factor: -1
    offset.storage.replication.factor: -1
    status.storage.replication.factor: -1
```

Command run to install:

```
kubectl apply -f kafka-connect.yaml -n kafka-connect
```

Note : Strimzi kafka is installed in namespace 'kafka', version - 3.0.0

I was expecting the KafkaConnect to get installed & the pods to be installed as well, however KafkaConnect resource is created, but not showing as Ready.
Also, the pods are not getting created.

```
(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:kafkaConnect karanalang$ kc get kafkaconnect my-connect-cluster -n kafka-connect
NAME                 DESIRED REPLICAS   READY
my-connect-cluster   1
```

On describing the my-connect-cluster, here is the output (not showing any errors)

```
(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:kafkaConnect karanalang$ kc describe kafkaconnect my-connect-cluster -n kafka-connect
Name:         my-connect-cluster
Namespace:    kafka-connect
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
Kind:         KafkaConnect
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-02-16T06:38:41Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:bootstrapServers:
        f:config:
          .:
          f:config.storage.replication.factor:
          f:config.storage.topic:
          f:group.id:
          f:offset.storage.replication.factor:
          f:offset.storage.topic:
          f:status.storage.replication.factor:
          f:status.storage.topic:
        f:replicas:
        f:tls:
          .:
          f:trustedCertificates:
        f:version:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2023-02-16T06:38:41Z
  Resource Version:  266457732
  UID:               bdd697f8-e38a-466b-8ddf-81ed1ae54efe
Spec:
  Bootstrap Servers:  versa-kafka-gke-kafka-bootstrap:9093
  Config:
    config.storage.replication.factor:  -1
    config.storage.topic:               connect-cluster-configs
    group.id:                           connect-cluster
    offset.storage.replication.factor:  -1
    offset.storage.topic:               connect-cluster-offsets
    status.storage.replication.factor:  -1
    status.storage.topic:               connect-cluster-status
  Replicas:                             1
  Tls:
    Trusted Certificates:
      Certificate:  ca.crt
      Secret Name:  versa-kafka-gke-cluster-ca-cert
  Version:          3.0.0
Events:             <none>
```

How do i debug/fix this ?

tia!

Update :
Based on note from Jakub, i re-installed kafkaconnect in the same namespace as Strimzi kafka (i.e. namespace - kafka), and pods are coming up now. However the logs show error as shown below :

```
(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:kafkaConnect karanalang$ kc logs -f pod/my-connect-cluster-connect-67f76f5d89-nv9sj -n kafka
Preparing truststore
Certificate was added to keystore
Preparing truststore is complete
Starting Kafka Connect with configuration:
# Bootstrap servers
bootstrap.servers=versa-kafka-gke-w-kafka-bootstrap:9093
# REST Listeners
rest.port=8083
rest.advertised.host.name=10.6.0.199 
rest.advertised.port=8083
# Plugins
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins
# Provided configuration
offset.storage.topic=connect-cluster-offsets
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
config.storage.topic=connect-cluster-configs
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
group.id=connect-cluster
status.storage.topic=connect-cluster-status
config.storage.replication.factor=-1
offset.storage.replication.factor=-1
status.storage.replication.factor=-1


security.protocol=SSL
producer.security.protocol=SSL
consumer.security.protocol=SSL
admin.security.protocol=SSL
# TLS / SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12
ssl.truststore.password=[hidden]
ssl.truststore.type=PKCS12

producer.ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12
producer.ssl.truststore.password=[hidden]

consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12
consumer.ssl.truststore.password=[hidden]

admin.ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12
admin.ssl.truststore.password=[hidden]



# Additional configuration
client.rack=

2023-02-17 06:43:08,952 INFO WorkerInfo values: 
    jvm.args = -Xms128M, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35, -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dkafka.logs.dir=/opt/kafka, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/kafka/custom-config/log4j.properties
    jvm.spec = Red Hat, Inc., OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.12, 11.0.12+7-LTS
    jvm.classpath = /opt/kafka/bin/../libs/accessors-smart-2.4.7.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/annotations-13.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/automaton-1.11-8.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/checker-qual-3.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-
......
2023-02-17 06:43:24,944 INFO Added alias 'InsertHeader' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertHeader' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added alias 'RegexRouter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added alias 'TimestampRouter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added alias 'ValueToKey' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added alias 'HasHeaderKey' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.HasHeaderKey' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added alias 'RecordIsTombstone' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.RecordIsTombstone' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added alias 'TopicNameMatches' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added alias 'BasicAuthSecurityRestExtension' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.BasicAuthSecurityRestExtension' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added aliases 'AllConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' and 'All' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.AllConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added aliases 'NoneConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' and 'None' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.NoneConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:24,945 INFO Added aliases 'PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' and 'Principal' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:25,347 INFO DistributedConfig values: 
    access.control.allow.methods = 
    access.control.allow.origin = 
    admin.listeners = null
    bootstrap.servers = [versa-kafka-gke-w-kafka-bootstrap:9093]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    config.providers = []
    config.storage.replication.factor = -1
    config.storage.topic = connect-cluster-configs
    connect.protocol = sessioned
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    connector.client.config.override.policy = All
    group.id = connect-cluster
    header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    inter.worker.key.generation.algorithm = HmacSHA256
    inter.worker.key.size = null
    inter.worker.key.ttl.ms = 3600000
    inter.worker.signature.algorithm = HmacSHA256
    inter.worker.verification.algorithms = [HmacSHA256]
    key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    listeners = [http://:8083]
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    offset.flush.interval.ms = 60000
    offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
    offset.storage.partitions = 25
    offset.storage.replication.factor = -1
    offset.storage.topic = connect-cluster-offsets
    plugin.path = [/opt/kafka/plugins]
    rebalance.timeout.ms = 60000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    response.http.headers.config = 
    rest.advertised.host.name = 10.6.0.199
    rest.advertised.listener = null
    rest.advertised.port = 8083
    rest.extension.classes = []
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    scheduled.rebalance.max.delay.ms = 300000
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.client.auth = none
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = /tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = PKCS12
    status.storage.partitions = 5
    status.storage.replication.factor = -1
    status.storage.topic = connect-cluster-status
    task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
    topic.creation.enable = true
    topic.tracking.allow.reset = true
    topic.tracking.enable = true
    value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    worker.sync.timeout.ms = 3000
    worker.unsync.backoff.ms = 300000
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:25,355 INFO Creating Kafka admin client (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:25,359 INFO AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [versa-kafka-gke-w-kafka-bootstrap:9093]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = /tmp/kafka/cluster.truststore.p12
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = PKCS12
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,848 WARN The configuration 'producer.ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,849 WARN The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,849 WARN The configuration 'rest.advertised.port' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,849 WARN The configuration 'plugin.path' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,850 WARN The configuration 'admin.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,850 WARN The configuration 'consumer.ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,850 WARN The configuration 'producer.ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,850 WARN The configuration 'status.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,850 WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,850 WARN The configuration 'consumer.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,851 WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,851 WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,851 WARN The configuration 'admin.ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,851 WARN The configuration 'consumer.ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,851 WARN The configuration 'config.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,851 WARN The configuration 'producer.security.protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,852 WARN The configuration 'rest.advertised.host.name' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,852 WARN The configuration 'status.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,852 WARN The configuration 'client.rack' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,852 WARN The configuration 'rest.port' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,853 WARN The configuration 'config.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,853 WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,855 WARN The configuration 'admin.ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,856 INFO Kafka version: 3.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,857 INFO Kafka commitId: 8cb0a5e9d3441962 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:27,857 INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1676616207856 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [main]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,857 INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Failed re-authentication with versa-kafka-gke-w-kafka-bootstrap/10.6.131.57 (Failed to process post-handshake messages) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,867 ERROR [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (versa-kafka-gke-w-kafka-bootstrap/10.6.131.57:9093) failed authentication due to: Failed to process post-handshake messages (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,870 WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed due to authentication error (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: Failed to process post-handshake messages
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:681)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:636)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:454)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:433)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:637)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:567)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1389)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1320)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:623)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:779)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2497)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1903)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:240)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decode(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:197)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decode(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    ... 16 more
2023-02-17 06:43:30,946 INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,947 INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata
2023-02-17 06:43:30,948 INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata
2023-02-17 06:43:30,949 INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Timed out 2 remaining operation(s) during close. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,959 INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,960 INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,961 INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics) [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1]
2023-02-17 06:43:30,961 ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed) [main]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:51)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:80)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: Failed to process post-handshake messages
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: Failed to process post-handshake messages
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:681)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:636)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:454)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:433)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:637)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:567)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1389)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1320)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:623)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:779)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2497)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1903)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:240)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decode(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:197)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.decode(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    ... 16 more
```

Pls note :
Strimzi Kafka version - 3.0.0, hence I've changed the version of kafkaconnect to - 3.0.0 as well.

Comment: I think you have to share more information in order to get some help: a) The logs from the Cluster operator; b) The logs from the Connect pods if they existc; c) heck the Kubernetes Events of the Pods and Deployment

Comment: You also say `Strimzi kafka is installed in namespace 'kafka'` => but does it watch the namespace `kafka-connect`?

Comment: @Jakub - Thanks! I re-installed kafkaconnect in the same namespace as kafka(i.e. namespace - kafka), and the pods are now getting created .. however, i see the error -> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch! in the logs. I've updated the description. Can you pls check & let me know. thnx!

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to use MirrorMaker2? Then you should be using that kind, not KafkaConnect.
https://strimzi.io/blog/2020/03/30/introducing-mirrormaker2/

And, as commented, ensure the operator is watching the namespace where you install any resources. Just because *you* can get/describe the resource doesn't mean the operator knows about it, or is processing it (look at its logs)

Comment: thnx, i'd checked the link you sent .. from what i understand, MirrorMaker2 relies on kafkaConnect & the yaml requires KafkaConnect to be specified eg: apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaMirrorMaker2
metadata:
  name: my-mirror-maker2
spec:
  version: 2.4.0
  connectCluster: "my-cluster-target" .. is that not correct ?

Comment: I believe only `sourceCluster`, `targetCluster`, and `sourceConnector` are required spec values. It will run its own Connect cluster, and not need to connect to an external one. Regarding TLS configs, I haven't configured MM2 with that before, so I'm not sure about those

Comment: thnx, let me check if I'm able to install MirrorMaker2 w/o having to to install kafkaConnect separately

Comment: That is a good point I somehow missed and focused only on the Connect deployment issue. But OneCricketeer is right -> you should use the KafkaMirrorMaker2 custom resource. Strimzi is using Connect to deploy Mirror Maker 2, but it is all done in the background by Strimzi. So you do not need to deploy a KafkaConnect cluster separately.

Comment: @Jakub - i've created a separate stackoverflow for KafkaMirrorMaker2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75517499/strimzi-kafkamirrormaker2-src-not-able-to-connect-to-target-cluster-src-tar